# Mapping Graphql to Grahpql+- (Dgraph version)

Tags: elixir, graphql, dgraph

I am using Dgraph and Postgres as my databases. I am using elixir with ecto to handle the graphql implementation from the frontend to the postgres db. I now need to map graphql queries to dgraph's version of graphql (graphql+-) so that I can use the power of graphql to get only the data I need. Is the best way to map graphql to graphql+- and how would you even do that? or is there another way to do it. I have tried to pass graphql queries directly to dgraph but as you can imagine that doesn't work. Is there another way that I haven't thought about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, I don't think so. GraphQL+- doesn't support all of GraphQL featues, so you'll have to write a transformer from GraphQL to GraphQL+-.

From official docs:

> We’ve modified the language to better support graph operations, adding and removing features to get the best fit for graph databases.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was afraid of, would the best way be to map json to json. eg. graphql query, send to transformation which modifies it slightly to fit graphql +- then do the opposite on the way back?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with GraphQL so I'm not sure about the actual differences between it and GraphQL+-, but I don't think you have many other choices. It of course depends on context of your aplication.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll stick the mapping idea. Thanks